# Iptables not working properly in ubuntu VM under utm app

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, scripting, iptables

I want to setup my ubuntu machine like this so that it only opens youtube.com and pw.live website and block all other outgoing traffic.

What I have done so far is created ip_table script below inside folder

```
/etc/iptables
```

```
#!/bin/bash

###### Flush existing rules
iptables -F

###### Allow DNS resolution
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

###### Allow loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

###### Load website rules from file
while read -r website; do
    iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d "$website" -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
done < /etc/iptables/websites.txt

###### Block everything else
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

##### Save the rules
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
####################
```

And in my website.txt I added

```
youtube.com
pw.live
www.youtube.com
www.pw.live
```

Problem I am facing is, that I can open YouTube.com but I can't play any video also in thumbnails it is just showing black screen.

How can I fix this?

Comment: IMO you'd have to whitelist a lot of additional domains : googlevideo.com, ytimg.com, ggpht.com (among potential others).

Answer (score 1):

You have two major issues contributing here. First, `iptables` works on IP addresses, not domain names. Large domains like YouTube have multiple IP addresses for geography-aware distribution through content delivery networks (CDNs) like Akamai. You're effectively only adding a single IP address from each set, which means you're leaving out a significant number of valid endpoints.

Your second set is that the actual videos are hosted on yet other domain names that you're not allowing. Yes, you'll have the same problem with names vs IPs for these additional domains.

What you probably want to do it stand up a proxy server that can use domain names, like [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.org) and then only allow your server to connect to that proxy for web services. You will determine the port your proxy listens to when you set it up, which will in turn determine the port you allow in `iptables`.